# Can't install anything new on Ubuntu (apt --fix-broken install)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, apt

When trying to install Sox on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with apt-get install sox, and I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 sox : Depends: libsox-fmt-alsa (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-ao (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-oss (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                libsox-fmt-pulse (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsox-fmt-base (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsox3 (= 14.4.2-3ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But then running the suggested apt `--fix-broken install` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-440 libnvidia-extra-440
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 431 not to upgrade.
48 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Continuing:

```
(Reading database ... 196302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am currently unable to install *anything* new on the machine, either at the command line or through the desktop. There appears to be a conflict between `/var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` and `/usr/include/cublas.h`. Having said that, since I want to upgrade to CUDA 11 (the machine runs CUDA 10 at the moment, with a Titan RTX card), I guess I can just go ahead and remove all CUDA packages with something like:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*
sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt remove --autoremove nvidia-*
```

followed by (to completely purge):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Or can I expect further problems with this?